# Assigning values to BigIntegers

Tags: java, biginteger, bigint

Suppose I do

```
BigInteger n;
```

Can I assign any value to n without it overflowing? For instance,

```
p = new BigInteger(512*512*512, 15, new Random());
n=p;
```

This is because I made RSA alg. and sometimes it gives me right values, while sometimes it gives me wrong ones and I want to make sure I don't overflow somewhere.

If overflow is the problem, should I, or how should I initialise my BigInts?

Comment: You should not do `n = p`, this assigns the reference;

Comment: Hm, that still doesn't explain why sometimes I get right values and sometimes I get wrong ones. Or maybe it does?

Comment: Use strings not Numbers

Comment: And how can I solve it? Thing is this will store 3 numbers of 512 bits each multiplied, so I need it to be like that to not overflow. I think....

Comment: Are you trying to create a random `BigInteger`?  Or one with a known value?  If you're after a known value, you have to create it from either a byte array or a String.

Comment: No, this will not store 3 numbers of 512 bits multiplied.

Comment: It will if I multiply them and assign the value to it.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc But to store the product of three numbers with bit lengths of 512, you only need a bit length of 1536, not 512 ^ 3.

Comment: You need 512 * 3 bits, not 512 ^ 3, basically, to represent the product of three numbers, each with 512 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I assign any value to n without it overflowing?

There are limits to what a `BigInteger` can represent.  As the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) says:

> "`BigInteger` must support values in the range -2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) to +2<sup>Integer.MAX_VALUE</sup> (exclusive) and may support values outside of that range."

Later on, it says:

> "`BigInteger` constructors and operations throw `ArithmeticException` when the result is out of the supported range ..."

... so you don't get unannounced overflows (like you do with primitive integer types) or INF/NaN-like values (like floating point types).

---

There is also the issue that if the heap is full / too small, creation of a large `BigInteger` will throw an OOME.

---

> If overflow is the problem ...

In your example, overflow in the `BigInteger` code it is not the problem.  You would be seeing exceptions of some kind.

Furthermore the expression `512*512*512` doesn't overflow.  (But in general, you could get an overflow in the constructor argument expressions ... because those calculations are typically done using primitive integer arithmetic, which overflows silently.)

<sup>(Pedantically ... the assignment `n = p;` is a reference assignment, and cannot overflow or throw an OOME.  AFAIK, there is no way that it can fail within the context of the Java model.  You'd need a hardware error, power failure, heap corruption, code generation bug, etc ...)</sup>

Comment: So... according to this his BigInteger should not overflow, right? 512^3 is just 2^27 which is small enough, right?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about the RSA algorithm, I suspect this is the code you actually wanted to write:

```
Random rand = new Random();
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(512, 15, rand);  // A random prime
BigInteger q = new BigInteger(512, 15, rand);  // Another random prime
BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);  // The product of the two primes
```

Comment: In particular, when you wrote `new BigInteger(512*512*512, ...)`, you were trying to create a 134217728-bit prime number, which is certainly *not* what you want.

Comment: Indeed I was trying to generate the private key `e`. I generate it until it `gcd(e,n)=1` and `e<n`. Thought this is where the problem comes from.